# Replace stock Status bar with an overlay?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, service, statusbar

There is an app called [StatusBar+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tombarrasso.android.wp7bar#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnRvbWJhcnJhc3NvLmFuZHJvaWQud3A3YmFyIl0.). What it basically does is replaces the stock status bar with a custom over lay.

I know this is easily done by a service and a view that will act as another status bar.

But, i am just wondering how it is capable of hiding the default status bar but still have spacing on top so it does not overlap applications. Or how does it actually overlay the status bar. Im just curious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It actually overlays the regular status bar itself. I managed to do it myself in a service:

```
view= new View(context);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        mStatusBarHeight,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR |  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
view.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR);        

view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setBackgroundColor(0x80FF0000);

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

wm.addView(view, params);
```

For more info see http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/